# select from two table with clouse count

Tags: sql, select

table1:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+
| Cust_id     | cust_name | car_id |
+-------------+-----------+--------+
|           1 | A         |      1 |
|           2 |   B       |      1 |
|           2 |     C     |      3 | 
+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

table2:

```
+-------------+---------+
| car_id      | name_car|
+-------------+---------+
|           1 | TOYOTA  |
|           2 | HONDA   |
+-------------+---------+
```

how to select the name_car that have two use in table1 like

```
+-------------+
| name_car    |
+-------------+
|  TOYOTA     |
+-------------+
```

and how to view like:

```
+-------------+---------+
| name_car    | COUNT   |
+-------------+---------+
|  TOYOTA     | 2       |
|  HONDA      | 1       |
+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far.  Is this MySQL or MS SQL?  You flagged it just as SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to select the name_car that have two use in table1

```
select q.name_car
from (
     select t2.name_car,count(t1.car_id) cnt
     from table1 t1
     join table2 t2 on t1.car_id=t2.car_id
     group by t1.name_car
 ) q
where q.cnt=2
```

> and how to view like:

```
select t2.name_car,count(t1.car_id)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.car_id=t2.car_id
group by t1.name_car
```

Comment: hello farheg,   

how about if there is name_car mitsubishi  in table2, 
but there no use it in table one, how can i select it to so the result show

name car                count

TOYOTA                 2
HONDA                   1
MITSUBISHI             0


thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.name_car, count(name_car)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.car_id = t1.car_id
group by t2.name_car
```